# mvvm using dagger2 with ViewModelFactory, dont understand default injection

Tags: android

I'm studying mvvm with AAC examples "https://github.com/android/architecture-samples".
hard to understand, I found something not understandable.
the project has ViewModel and ViewModelFactory. 
the point I wanna know is that how the ViewModel of TaskFragment is injected by DefaultTasksRepository.

```
class TasksFragment : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val viewModel by viewModels<TasksViewModel> { viewModelFactory }
}
```

```
class TasksViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tasksRepository: TasksRepository
) : ViewModel() {
}
```

```
class DefaultTasksRepository @Inject constructor(
    @TasksRemoteDataSource private val tasksRemoteDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    @TasksLocalDataSource private val tasksLocalDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : TasksRepository {
}
```

```
interface TasksRepository {

    suspend fun getTasks(forceUpdate: Boolean = false): Result<List<Task>>

    suspend fun getTask(taskId: String, forceUpdate: Boolean = false): Result<Task>

    suspend fun saveTask(task: Task)

    suspend fun completeTask(task: Task)

    suspend fun completeTask(taskId: String)

    suspend fun activateTask(task: Task)

    suspend fun activateTask(taskId: String)

    suspend fun clearCompletedTasks()

    suspend fun deleteAllTasks()

    suspend fun deleteTask(taskId: String)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. DefaultTasksRepository @Inject constructor(), this has been registered in dagger so that we can use its reference from anywhere.
2. TasksViewModel @Inject constructor(), this will create TasksViewModel reference but before that it will create instance of DefaultTasksRepository and will pass into constructor of TasksViewModel.
3. Then you can inject TasksViewModel and use anywhere.

Comment: why TaskViewModel create instance DefaultTasksRepository? that is the core of this question.

Comment: Because TaskViewModel needs instance of DefaultTasksRepository and we have provided Construction Injector of DefaultTasksRepository to dagger, which tells dagger to create instance of DefaultTasksRepository when its required. Its magic of Dagger.  Ref - https://dagger.dev/users-guide.html. Use @Inject to annotate the constructor that Dagger should use to create instances of a class. When a new instance is requested, Dagger will obtain the required parameters values and invoke this constructor.

Comment: the TaskViewModel refer to Default+TasksRepository? you mean Dagger join tasksRepository in(TasksViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tasksRepository: TasksRepository
) : ViewModel()) with Default+TasksRepository?

Comment: Yes, because, DefaultTasksRepository has TasksRepository implementation. Its dagger advantages.

Comment: You are most welcome. In future, don't hesitate for further query. I am available to help you any time bro. :)